# Is this a list of array or a method or array object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-3.0

I'm busy learning thru MSDN documentation how to implement a Web API, and just want to know the meaning of this below code as it's confusing me; specially **Product[] products = new Product[]**

where does **products** object come from, and why does it have **[ ]** like a array?

Is it a list of array or a method or a object array ?

Taken from MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

```
Product[] products = new Product[] 
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };
```

Comment: Its an array of `Product`'s not a method.

Comment: an array of products. the stuff in the curly brackets are the elements of the array. now that you mention it it does kind of look like a method :)

Comment: @user8189 It's an array of object type `Product` and it is being initialized with 3 `Product` objects, with properties `Id`, `Name`, `Category`, and `Price` being set on initialization of each `Product` object.

Comment: "why does it have [ ] like a array?2 Because it **is** an array?

Comment: thanks, but where does "products" object come from? as in the whole tutorial I can't find "products", apart from the controller name !!!

Comment: @user8189 It's an example class, I would wager. Primarily used for example purposes.

Comment: it comes from your code. You create a new array of type `Product`. Your controller just *references* that array in order to display its elements.

Comment: This is a combination of [array initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization) and [object initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an array of *Product* objects.

Comment: 6 comments that explain this isn't enough? How is this answer *more useful and complete* than the comments?

Comment: I made my post literally 1 minute after your first comment. Also, from the help page on what **not** to do in comments: "Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)"

Comment: You´re right that your answer is an answert to the question being **posted** However one may ask: is this the OPs **actual** question? Honestly I don´t know, which is why I voted to close as unclear. We simply don´t know exactly what OPs problem is. Of course the obvious question is "what is `product[]`? For that question your answer is absouletely correct. However I have strong feeling that´s not OPs actual problem.

Comment: @matkv I understand, but TBH, it seems OP didn't research first and hence why probably no one else bothered to write an answer. You didn't answer my question, `How is this answer more useful and complete`, how about an explanation of what makes an array, how they are used; expand on your post to help make your answer more complete. If I was strolling along looking for help, the answer honestly doesn't explain *why*...

Comment: @HimBromBeere I would say so: "_Is it a list of array or a method or a object array?_" It is an object array, an array of product objects.

Comment: I didn´t say your answer is whrong - which it apparently is not. All I said is that it is unlikely to help anyone, maybe not even the OP.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I didn't answer your question because you edited it after I already replied, sorry - didn't see it. I'm not saying that it's more useful or complete, but it's an answer - posted as an answer. According to StackOverflows own guidelines your comment shouldn't have been a comment in the first place.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If you think that that's fair, that's what the downvote/flag functions are here for I guess.

Comment: Do you refer to your answer or to the question? Which one should I flag/vote to close/downvote?

Comment: @HimBromBeere my answer

Comment: Flagging isn´t appropriate here, as I already mentioned: your answer is an answer to the question being posted. So all I can do is downvoting your answer, because I don´t think its meaningful to anyone.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that's perfectly fine